# 'web' is not a valid database version in this edition of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, dotnetnuke

Aha! -- this is probably it. On the very weekend I elected to set up the DNN site on Azure ... Web and Business versions are deprecated / retired. As of yesterday in fact, this is what is on Azure.

The ONLY 2 choices in SQL Server 2012 SSMS however, to import a data tier app are just Web and Business. Basic, Standard and Premium are not in the drop down in SSMS 2012.

So ... rather than just zap this question I'll put in another question within it.  Is there an update to SSMS 2012? I ask because the database being migrated is 2012 so using SSMS 2014 may not work, if the option is to download this version of SSMS and use it.

Other than that ... here's what's already posted:

Note, the SQL Server database being migrated is 2012. DNN Version is 07.02.01 (367).

I'm following the steps in this blog link to migrate a DNN site to Azure: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154975/moving-a-dnn-install-to-microsoft-azure-websites.  The error I get is:

> 'web' is not a valid database version in this edition of SQL Server.

I have 2 choices in the import process 'Web' and 'Business', tried both and neither will work. There are a few other Stack Overflow questions on this but these are either not answered or the answers don't work.

I realize this is vague but it's simple enough: It doesn't work. :) The blog is followed to the letter. The `.bacpac` file is created with no errors.  Importing the data tier step just results in the error that creating the target database on Azure failed for the above reason.

I have a support ticket in to Azure for this as well.

There has to be a simple, overlooked something -- a missing config step on setting up Azure. It could be the free trial doesn't cover this and I need to pay for something. That's fine ... just need to know what it is.

Who has run into this and actually, factually solved it?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is **always to use the latest SSMS version available**, in order to have the latest updates supporting new Azure features like: full-text search support for Azure SQL Server v12, the long requested "Edit top 200 rows" working, the table designer, and a long etc.

Note that the latest SSMS release supports SQL Server 2016 through SQL Server 2005, so is going to work fine with your SQL Server 2012 database. On the SSMS June 2015 Preview, the following item was added:

- Import/Export wizard support for new Azure SQL Database service tiers (Basic, Standard, Premium).

You can read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Updating my SSMS to 2016 did the trick. I was using 2014, but that still threw the error.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3031047

For future reference. This hotfix should work on this problem.

Comment: In my case it did not, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That is because the valid database version could be `basic` or `standard` or `premium`. SSMS does not allow to choose it, therefore, the solution is to download the latest version of SSMS.